# i want to find a common character from n number string inside a single multidimensional list using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def bibek(): 
  test_list=[[]]
  x=int(input("Enter the length of String elements using enter -: "))
   for i in range(0,x):
     a=str(input())
     a=list(a)
     test_list.append(a)
   del(test_list[0]):
   def filt(b):
      d=['b','i','b']
      if b in d:
        return True
      else:
        return False
   for t in test_list:
      x=filter(filt,t)
   for i in x:
      print(i)
bibek()
```

suppose `test_list=[['b','i','b'],['s','i','b'],['r','i','b']]`
output should be ib  since ib is common among all

Answer (score 0):

an option is to use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and its methods:

```
test_list=[['b','i','b'],['s','i','b'],['r','i','b']]

common = set(test_list[0])
for item in test_list[1:]:
    common.intersection_update(item)
print(common)  # {'i', 'b'}
```

---

UPDATE: now that you have clarified your question i would to this:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

test_list=[['b','i','b','b'],['s','i','b','b'],['r','i','b','b']]


# convert the list to simple strings
strgs = [''.join(item) for item in test_list]

common = strgs[0]
for item in strgs[1:]:
    sm = SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=item, b=common)
    match = sm.find_longest_match(0, len(item), 0, len(common))
    common = common[match.b:match.b+match.size]

print(common)  # 'ibb'
```

the trick here is to use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html?highlight=difflib%20sequencematcher#difflib.SequenceMatcher) in order to get the longest string.

---

one more update after clarification of your question this time using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter


strgs='app','bapp','sardipp', 'ppa'

common = Counter(strgs[0])
print(common)
for item in strgs[1:]:
    c = Counter(item)
    for key, number in common.items():
        common[key] = min(number, c.get(key, 0))

print(common)  # Counter({'p': 2, 'a': 1})
print(sorted(common.elements()))  # ['a', 'p', 'p']
```

Comment: i am also doing same thing but what if input is   test_list=[['b','i','b','b'],['s','i','b','b'],['r','i','b','b']]     output should be  ibb but  your code give only ib instead of ibb becoz of set,,,

Comment: ohh bt i am getting one wrong  output while i am entring [['b','i','b','b'],['s','i','b','b'],['r','i','b','b'],['s','u','m','b','i','b']]  it is giving only ib but it should be ibb  na  ,, can u plz solve the issue

Comment: sry bt it is not fix that all index contain same length  ,,,

Comment: [['b','i','b','b'],['s','i','b','b'],['r','i','b','b'],['s','u','m','b','i','b']] for thiss code is giving ib only bt  common is ibb

Comment: in string bibb, sibb, ribb and sumbib  --alphabet ibb is common i.e 2-b and 1-i is common among all .

Comment: again for string app,bapp,sardipp, ppa  for this ,,output should be app  but ur code is giving only pp

Comment: yes i updated bt for this input app,bapp,sardipp, ppa  output should be app but ur updated code is giving only pp

Comment: yes that is working thank u so much bt can you make it as work for user input

Comment: anyway thank you so much for guiding me  because your code help me a lot ,, thank u once again

Comment: i got my problem solved from your code thank u so much

Comment: then please [upvote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer. thank you.